# how to install php amqp in ubuntu

Tags: php, rabbitmq, ubuntu-10.04

I am try to install amqp for php (Integrating PHP with RabbitMQ)
using this http://code.google.com/p/php-amqp/.

after run 
phpize && ./configure --with-amqp && make && sudo make install

it give error like this

**Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module**

Please help me, my environment is ubuntu

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to download the code for the PHP library from here: http://code.google.com/p/php-amqp/downloads/list

Then `cd` into that folder and run the command they tell you to run.

UPDATE: That page is actually an old page, they haven't updated it in a long time. You can grab the latest amqp from http://pecl.php.net/get/amqp:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/amqp -O amqp.tar.gz
tar -zxvf amqp.tar.gz
cd amqp-1.0.7    # replace this with the current version
phpize
./configure --with-amqp
make
sudo make install
```

Then you'll need to add the following line to your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=amqp.so
```

Comment: Could you @robbrit Werlich please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 17):

Let's make life easier, we have tow options:

1. If you're using Debian, you can easily install the AMQP extension for PHP with the following command (adjust the PHP version to match your setup):

```
    sudo apt install php7.4-amqp
```

<sup>This command not only installs the extension but also takes care of enabling it in your php.ini configuration file.</sup>

2. Another option is to install the extension via PECL using this command:

```
    pecl install amqp
```

After a successful installation, make sure to add the following line to your php.ini configuration file (be sure to provide the full path to the extension): `extension = amqp.so`

<sup>This allows PHP to recognize and load the AMQP extension.</sup>

Comment: `php7.4-amqp`  for relevant versions etc

Answer (score 4):

> You cannot use the
> "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Amqp\Transport\Connection" as the
> "amqp" extension is not installed.

```
 sudo apt install php-amqp -y
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the required libraries and tools to compile a PHP extension.

On Debian/Ubuntu you can get them with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Comment: Actually I've spent a whole day trying to install the extension in my production machine and I still didn't manage to install it. Why aren't there precompiled downloads of the extension for the most popular distros? It's absurd that I have to install a bunch of development tools in the production server just to be able to install one library. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: `php5-dev` would install other things which you do not want to have on a production machine.